# Can you use glColor3f() whilst bypassing the fragment shader?

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

I am writing an OpenGL program that renders a triangle mesh using a vertex shader and a fragment shader. In my fragment shader, I set all these triangles to be green. I now also want to draw on the axes of the model's coordinate system. However, I don't want to do this by creating a triangle mesh, as this seems overkill, so I want to use the old-fashioned method of drawing lines, such as:

```
glLineWidth(2.5);
glBegin(GL_LINES);
glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glVertex3f(10, 0, 0);
glEnd();
```

Here, I want these axes to be red. The problem is that the axes are always drawn in green. I assume that this is because my fragment shader is set to draw everything in green:

```
#version 330

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

So, is it possible to use functions such as glColor3f() to determine the colour of a line, without it then being overridden by the fragment shader?

Comment: If you have programmable pipeline, it doesn't have any sense to use immediate mode.

Comment: "as this seems overkill" welcome to the world of Modern OpenGL, where you need buffers and shaders even to draw **one** small triangle.